# Ansible: extracting values from nested dictionaries

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook `abc.yml` whose content is like this.

```yaml
- name: Debug a message
  debug:
    msg: |
         networks: {{ targetserver_networks }}
  loop: "{{ machinesvar }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: targetserver_networks
```

Another file, `123.json` is like this,

```json
{
  "server1": {
    "domain": "abc.com",
    "networks": {
                 "testnet1" : ["em1", "10.10.10.1"],
                 "testnet2" : ["em2", "10.10.10.2"]
                }
  },
  "server2": {
    "domain": "abc.com",
    "networks": {
                 "testnet1" : ["em1", "10.10.10.3"],
                 "testnet2" : ["em2", "10.10.10.4"]
                }
```

I am calling my main.yaml like this..

```yaml
- name: create 
  hosts: all

  vars:

    machines : "{{ lookup('file','123.json') | from_json }}"

  tasks:

  - name: Create Networks(s)
    include_tasks:
      file: abc.yaml        
    vars:
      nodename: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      machinesvar: "{{ machines[nodename] | dict2items }}"
```

The output which I am getting is as below..

```json
TASK [Debug a message] ***********************************************************
ok: [server1] => (item={'key': 'domain', 'value': 'abc.com'}) => {
    "msg": "networks: {'key': 'domain', 'value': 'abc.com'}\n"
}
ok: [server1] => (item={'key': 'networks', 'value': {'testnet1': ['em1', '10.10.10.1'], 'testnet2': ['em2', '10.10.10.1']}}) => {
    "msg": "networks: {'key': 'networks', 'value': {'testnet1': ['em2', '10.10.10.2'], 'testnet2': ['em2', '10.10.10.2']}}\n"
}
```

In `abc.yaml`, I want to check if network name is `testnet1` and then use the values (`['em1', '10.10.10.1']`) to do some other operation.

How can I extract these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've placed your `dict2items` filter at the wrong point in your playbook. You want to pass `machines[inventory_hostname]` to `abc.yaml`, and then convert the `networks` key into a list with `dict2items`. That is, if we have `playbook.yaml` like this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: 123.json
        name: machines

    - name: create networks
      include_tasks:
        file: abc.yaml
      vars:
        nodename: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        machinesvar: "{{ machines[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

Then we can write `abc.yaml` like this:

```yaml
- name: Debug a message
  debug:
    msg:
      networks: "Do something with interface {{ item.value.0 }}, address {{ item.value.1 }}"
  when: item.key == "testnet1"
  loop: "{{machinesvar.networks|dict2items}}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

Running this produces:

```
TASK [Debug a message] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1] => (item=testnet1) => {
    "msg": {
        "networks": "Do something with interface em1, address 10.10.10.1"
    }
}
skipping: [server1] => (item=testnet2)
ok: [server2] => (item=testnet1) => {
    "msg": {
        "networks": "Do something with interface em1, address 10.10.10.3"
    }
}
skipping: [server2] => (item=testnet2)
```